# Tfs missing a PDF mapping

Tags: pdf, tfs

I am trying to add a MSI project to TFS. The system that the MSI file installs has a PDF manual, so this PDF manuel is part of the project. But when I try to add the project, I get following error:

The item 'manal.pdf' cannot be added to source control because the item has no source control mapping.....

Can I do something about this? Of course TFS cannot detect changes etc. I simply want to store it along with the other files.

Comment: Is the pdf located in your workspace or do you want to add it from somewhere else? Which version of TFS and TeamExplorer do you use? I tried the same in my system (from outer workspace and inside), but I had no issues.

Comment: Hi Mike, I user visual studio 2013 and visualstudio.com as tfs repo. It is a PDF which is part of the msi project. TIA

Comment: Even if it's part of the  project, is it located in the same folder? Here someone had a similar problem: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/f99551c4-340d-408f-8885-6e979a0cba7b/cannot-be-added-because-the-item-has-no-source-control-mapping?forum=tfsgeneral

Comment: It is a bad practice to store binary files in source control. I would just reference the inline manual...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See Mikes comment with a post from a ms group